# launching avd android api level 17

Tags: android

I've tried to launch avd on api level 17, it takes too much time to do it
I've waited for 2hours but it is still working on. the only thing i can see is "Android" preparing sign on the screen
I chose
CPU/ABI : ARM(armeabi-v7a)
Target : Android 4.2(API LEVEL 17)
Memory option : Ram : 512 VM Heap : 64
Internal storage : 200 mib
SD card : 100mib
is it because my laptop is too slow to launch it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons why your AVD is slow. It'll mostly have to do with your development machine speed but there are optimisations you can do. The AVD needs to provide an emulator with a complete system image. The emulator virtualizes a complete device: hardware, kernel, low-level system libraries, and app framework. The intel x86 images are much better though and google did make some improvements with the release of r17 developer tools.

see:

- [How to speed up Android Emulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924920/how-to-speed-up-android-emulation)
- http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/
- http://droidtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-speed-up-avd.html
- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager/
- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html